# PHP returns "Warning: Unable to save result set" but MySQL workbench returns correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I have been struggling with this for a few days now :'-( My class returns an array of matched numbers from 2 tables.

```
SELECT R.*, L.* 
FROM LSR_pool_TBL AS R, LRP_pool_TBL AS L
WHERE((R.LSR_CELL_NO = L.LRP_cellNo)
    OR (R.LSR_WORK_NO = L.LRP_cellNo)
    OR (R.LSR_ALT_NO = L.LRP_cellNo)
    OR (R.LSR_HOME_NO = L.LRP_cellNo))
```

When I run the query above, in MySQL Workbench I get the desired result however, when I run the query in PHP I get the "Warning: Unable to save result set" but both tables have data. Table 1 has 250000 records and table 2 has 3800 records in it.

I have tried setting "mysql_query("SET SQL_BIG_TABLES=1");" as was one suggestion, but that had no effect.

Adding to my frustration is that I do not have access to the logs on the server.

Does anyone have any suggestions...?

Comment: Then you had better show us the PHP code and not just the query

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in _mew_ code **a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Sorry RiggsFolly, I usually use mysqli, but this is a legacy system that desperately needs to be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have 2 issues going on either PHP memory error OR a PHP MYSQL buffer error.
To fix the php memory error increase the `memory_limit`

```
ini_set("memory_limit","256m");
```

or higher.
To fix the PHP / Mysql issue run the query unbuffered.  Since I don't know which MYSQL driver you are using, here's the direct link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php

Comment: Thanks Forbs, the unbuffered query worked perfectly.